# Check constraint on grouped conditions

Tags: sql-server-2014, alter-table, check-constraints, ddl-trigger

Take the following table as an example:

```
GroupID    AlphaID     BetaID

1          0           1
1          1           1
1          2           2
2          0           1
2          1           2   
2          2           2
2          3           2
3          0           1   
3          1           1
```

I would like to write a check constraint that checks the following:

**1. AlphaID - Check Constraint**

- The first instance of `AlphaID` in a `GroupID` must start at 0

  - E.g inserting *GroupID = 4* with an *AlphaID = 0* will succeed
  - E.g inserting *GroupID = 4* with an *AlphaID = 1* will fail
- `AlphaID` must be unique within each `GroupID` and must be +1 greater than current max `AlphaID`

  - E.g inserting *GroupID = 3* with an *AlphaID = 1* will fail (duplicate)
  - E.g inserting *GroupID = 3* with an *AlphaID = 2* will succeed (current max + 1)
  - E.g inserting *GroupID = 3* with an *AlphaID = 4* will fail (out of order)

**2. BetaID - Check Constraint**

- The first instance of `BetaID` in a `GroupID` must start at 1

  - E.g inserting *GroupID = 4* with an *BetaID = 0* will fail
  - E.g inserting *GroupID = 4* with an *BetaID = 1* will succeed
- `BetaID` can have duplicates within `GroupID` or may be +1 greater than current max `BetaID`

  - E.g inserting *GroupID = 3* with an *BetaID = 1* will succeed
  - E.g inserting *GroupID = 3* with an *BetaID = 2* will succeed
  - E.g inserting *GroupID = 3* with an *BetaID = 4* will fail (out of order)

**A solution that uses a trigger may also be suitable.**

Comment: *The first instance of* The table is a heap. So "first/next/last" not defined in a table. It may be defined only in a query with proper ORDER BY clause.

Comment: The task may be solved by a trigger with the logic: 1) Do not allow insertion if a record with inserted GroupID value not exists in a table and inserted AlphaID is not 0; 2) Do not allow insertion if a record with inserted GroupID value not exists in a table and inserted BetaID is not 1; 3) Do not allow insertion if a record with inserted GroupID value exists in a table and inserted AlphaID is not MAX(AlphaID)+1 for this GroupID; 4)  Do not allow insertion if a record with inserted GroupID value exists in a table and inserted BetaID is not MAX(AlphaID) or MAX(AlphaID)+1 for this GroupID;

Comment: @Akina as I suspected a trigger is the most suitable way to do this. Thank you for your reply.